# Singly linked list deleting the last node

Tags: c++, linked-list

How can i delete the last node in a singly linked list? It's not like with head when i could just write this :

```
void DeleteNode ( node *& head, node *& tail, int val )
{
    node * p = nullptr;
    node * tmp = nullptr;

    if ( val == head -> data )
    {
      delete head;
      head = head -> next;
    }
...
```

I can delete the last node like that :

```
if ( val == tail -> data )
{
    delete tail;
}
```

But then how can i set the tail to the previous node ( In doubly linked list, I could just write tail = tail -> prev to switch to previous node ).

I tried something like that :

```
tail = head;
while ( tail != nullptr ) 
{
    tail = tail -> next
}
```

But it should not work because the last tail node which i deleted is still somewhere in the memory and the previous node still points there so it does not point to NULL and it won't stop there.

List structure :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;

    node() : next ( nullptr ) { }

};
```

Comment: Why are there so many linked list questions at the moment? Is it university linked list teaching time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the last node using your code but it is not clearing the tail entry from the linked list.

To solve your issue you have to travel to the nearest node of tail node from there,

1. you have to delete the last node
2. set `null` to the `next` of nearest node.

Now see the proper code,

```
prev = NULL;
tail = head;
while (tail->next != NULL) {
    prev = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
}
delete tail; // tail points to the last node
if (prev) {
    prev->next = NULL; // now pre points to the new last node
}
```